# Return parameters in Kubeflow pipeline component

Tags: kubeflow, kubeflow-pipelines

Im trying to return several parameters from a kubeflow component. Following the documentation it says you should use OutputPath where T is one of the types in python (str, float, int...) so I have this:

```
@component
def basic_data_drifting(current_csv: Input[Dataset],
                        reference_csv: Input[Dataset],
                        report_html: Output[HTML],
                        data_drift_score: OutputPath(float),
                        value: OutputPath(float)):
```

I know, for the documentation, that if my parameter is a string, I should use:

```
with open(myoutputpathstr, 'w') as output_file:
    output_file.write("my string")
```

But I cant find any example of returning floats. ints, bools... should I cast them to str? always storing them as a file? Whats the point of having `<T>` instead of only str?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here are two ways to get the data from `component`

1. using `return` from component function
2. save and load data with `from kfp.components import OutputPath`

I provides examples about `return`, `OutputPath`, `InputPath` with code.

1. case 1: return single value, type of `<T>`

   ```
   from kfp.components import func_to_container_op   
   # I make component using `kfp.components.func_to_container_op`

   def case_1(value_1: int, value_2: int) -> int:  # to use return, write '-> {type}' 
       result = value_1 + value_2       

       return result    # it can be int, float, bouble, str, bool, .... 

   case_1_op = func_to_container_op(func = case_1,
                                    base_image = 'case_1/tag:0.1',
                                 output_component_file="case_1.component.yaml")
   ```
2. case 2: return multiple value

   ```
   from kfp.components import func_to_container_op   
   from typing import NamedTuple

   # If there are multiple return values, wrap them in a tuple.
   # And use `NamedTuple`
   def case_2(value_1: int) -> NamedTuple('Output', [("key_of_foo", int), 
                                                     ('key_of_bar', str),
                                                     ('key_of_baz', bool)]):
       foo = value_1        # int
       bar = "2"            # str
       baz = True           # bool

       return (foo, bar, baz)      #  wrap them in a tuple.

   case_2_op = func_to_container_op(func = case_2,
                                    base_image = 'case_2/tag:0.1',
                                 output_component_file="case_2.component.yaml")
   ```
3. case 3: save data to file using `kfp.components.OutputPath`.

   ```
   def case_3(value_1: str, value_2: int, value_3: bool,
           file_path: OutputPath("dict")):      
           # 'OutputPath' has a naming rule: it must end with `_path`.

       import json
       exam_dict = dict(one = value_1,
                         two = [value_2, value_3])

       json.dump(exam_dict, open(file_path, "w"), indent=4) 

   case_3_op = func_to_container_op(func = case_3,
                                    base_image = 'case_3/tag:0.1',
                                 output_component_file="case_3.component.yaml")
   ```
4. case 4: load data from file using `kfp.components.InputPath`.

```
def case_4(data_input: InputPath("dict")): 
    import json
    
    with open(data_input, "r", encoding='utf-8') as f:
        data = json.load(f)
    
    print(data)     # {'one': '2', 'two': [1, True]}
 
case_4_op = func_to_container_op(func = case_4,
                                 base_image = 'case_4/tag:0.1',
                              output_component_file="case_4.component.yaml")
```

**pipeline**

```py
import kfp.dsl as dsl

@dsl.pipeline(name="example")
def data_example(value_1: int, value_2:int):
    _case_1_op = case_1_op(value_1, value_2)
    
    # case of input from single return
    _case_2_op = case_2_op(_case_1_op.output)   
    
    # case of input from multi value return. input value using key.
    # key name must match each key in the NamedTuple.
    _case_3_op = case_3_op(_case_2_op.outputs['key_of_bar'], _case_2_op.outputs['key_of_foo'], _case_2_op.outputs['key_of_baz'])
    
    # case of input from path. input path using key.
    # The key name must match the OutputPath name without '_path'.
    _case_4_op = case_4_op(_case_3_op.outputs["file"])
```

I'm not sure if this answer is what you asked for, but I hope this helps.

Comment: How about returning a custom type for example a user-defined class type?

Answer (score 0):

[This documentation](https://github.com/kubeflow/pipelines/blob/master/samples/core/lightweight_component/lightweight_component.ipynb) shows exactly what you need - returning multiple outputs of different datatypes.

If you are new to Kubeflow, use this [collection of examples](https://github.com/kubeflow/examples) provided by Kubeflow as a source of reference.

You can also take a look at a [minimal sample pipeline here](https://medium.com/@trannhatquang1104/minimal-kubeflow-pipeline-example-f13cd5dc84ac).

Happy experimenting!